Issue with Opening NetBeans TopComponent at Startup
I'm working on a NetBeans Platform application and I want to open a TopComponent automatically when the application starts. Despite following the typical steps, my TopComponent does not open at startup.
Here are the steps I have followed:

Created the TopComponent:
package com.example.myapp;

import org.openide.windows.TopComponent;
import org.openide.awt.ActionID;
import org.openide.awt.ActionReference;
import org.openide.util.NbBundle.Messages;

@TopComponent.Description(
        preferredID = "MyTopComponent",
        persistenceType = TopComponent.PERSISTENCE_ALWAYS
)
@TopComponent.Registration(
        mode = "editor",
        openAtStartup = false // I handle the opening manually
)
@ActionID(category = "Window", id = "com.example.myapp.MyTopComponent")
@ActionReference(path = "Menu/Window", position = 0)
@Messages({
    "CTL_MyTopComponent=My TopComponent",
    "HINT_MyTopComponent=This is a MyTopComponent window"
})
public final class MyTopComponent extends TopComponent {

    public MyTopComponent() {
        initComponents();
        setName(Bundle.CTL_MyTopComponent());
        setToolTipText(Bundle.HINT_MyTopComponent());
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        // Initialize your components here
    }

    public static synchronized MyTopComponent getInstance() {
        MyTopComponent instance = (MyTopComponent) WindowManager.getDefault().findTopComponent("MyTopComponent");
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new MyTopComponent();
        }
        return instance;
    }
} 



Created an Installer class to handle the startup logic:


package com.example.myapp;

import org.openide.modules.ModuleInstall;
import org.openide.windows.WindowManager;

public class Installer extends ModuleInstall {

    @Override
    public void restored() {
        WindowManager.getDefault().invokeWhenUIReady(() -> {
            MyTopComponent tc = MyTopComponent.getInstance();
            if (tc != null) {
                tc.open();
                tc.requestActive();
            }
        });
    }
}


Registered the Installer class in the manifest.mf file:

Manifest-Version: 1.0
OpenIDE-Module: com.example.myapp
OpenIDE-Module-Specification-Version: 1.0
OpenIDE-Module-Install: com/example/myapp/Installer.class

Despite following these steps, the TopComponent does not open at startup. Here are additional details and steps I've taken to debug the issue:

Verified that the Installer class is correctly placed in the specified package.
Checked NetBeans logs for any errors or warnings related to the TopComponent or Installer (none found).
Cleaned and rebuilt the module.
Tried running the module in a clean
NetBeans user directory.

What could be causing the TopComponent to not open at startup, and how can I resolve this issue?
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Using ModuleInstall/restored() is probably too early, Netbeans UI is not ready yet.
Instead, try the same with @onShowing, so that your code is called when UI is ready:
@onShowing
public class OpenStart implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        WindowManager.getDefault().invokeWhenUIReady(() -> {
            MyTopComponent tc = MyTopComponent.getInstance();
            if (tc != null) {
                tc.open();
                tc.requestActive();
            }
        });
    }
}


I think you don't have to use anymore WindowManager.getDefault().invokeWhenUIReady() in the run() method.
